# Python: Using find function not in order

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

So the code below takes a string of inputted information (A math expression), and uses the find function to find one of the operators in "*/+-" and separates the string accordingly.

```
def splitting1(z):
    for operators in "*/+-":
        if operators in z:
            position1= z.find(operators)
            position2= z.rfind(operators)
            text_before_operators= (z[:position1]).strip()
            text_after_operators= (z[(position1+1):(position2)]).strip()
            return text_before_operators,text_after_operators
```

My problem is that if I have an inputted expression such as `3/5*7` then `position1` will first find `*` before finding `/`. I want the code to associate 'position1' with the left most operator. Is there a way to omit operator precedence when using the for/in functions? If not, is there a better string manipulator that can omit the order of precedence.

Note z is the input. And the input is limited to two operators in case that created ambiguity.

Comment: note: operator is a module name, so may be considered bad practice to use it in your function.

Comment: if you're trying to evaluate a math expression, this is not how it's done. Read your input sequentially, split it into tokens (numbers, operators) and place tokens in correct "positions" using a parsing algorithm, like shunting yard or top-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over `*/+-`, so the first character that's found is the first one that's returned.

You basically want to find the indexes of all of these operators and then find the largest or the smallest. Try re-writing this function to work for other side of the string:

```
def find_operator_right(text):
    position = -1

    for oper in '*/+-':
        index = text.rfind(oper)

        if index > position:
            position = index

    return position
```

A slightly more Pythonic solution would be something like this:

```
right_index = max(map(text.rfind, '+-/*'))
```

Comment: You're checking to see if `index > position`. `-1` is just the smallest index that can be returned by `find`.

Comment: So tell me if I got this right: Your code first uses text.rfind(oper) to find the first operator from "*/-+", if one of those is found then it takes the index, and assigns the value to a variable called position. But if I had an expression like 4*3/2, wouldnt it just set the index to 4, and then set position =4, If we replaced text.rfind with text.find and the expression from 4*3/2 to 4/2*3 then the same problem would exist as metioned in the op?

Comment: This code takes care of the iteration. It's just like `rfind`, but it searches for the right-most character from the list of choices.

Comment: oh wait, I think I see it. If I wrote a new function that looked at the expression from the left I would have two position values, I could use some code to determine the lower position value and extrapolate it from the string with some other code. Is this what you're trying to get at?

Comment: `find_operator_right(text)` returns the index of the right-most operator in the string. If you can write `find_operator_left`, these two functions will give you the indexes of the two operators in the string.

Comment: Hey when I make a "left" function here I still do not get correct output. Inputting an expression 6/7/8 will give index 1 and 3 for left and right BUT inputting something like 6/7*8 gives an index of 3 and 3 for left and right?.

Comment: @user1716168: Post your code. The operators shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to lex, so I suggest you look into modules designed especially for this purpose, for example [`ply`](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).

.

Saying that, I think you are on the right track for this example, but you are missing some **recursion** (to make a more general lexer for these):

```
def splitting1(z):
    for char in "*/+-":
        if char in z:
            position = z.find(char)
            text_before_operator= (z[:position]).strip()
            text_after_operator= (z[position+1:]).strip()
            return (char, splitting1(text_before_operator), splitting1(text_after_operator))
    return ("number", z)
```

One way to find the left-most operator regardless of precedence i.e. omit operator precedence, is to rearrange what you iterate over:

```
def splitting2(z):
    for char in z:
        if char in "*/+-":
            position = z.find(char)
            text_before_operator= (z[:position]).strip()
            text_after_operator= (z[position+1:]).strip()
            return (char, splitting2(text_before_operator), splitting2(text_after_operator))
    return ("number", z)
```

*Note these function return a different result to your original function.*

Comment: Really?? So I just had to switch the two lines, oh wow, thanks. But why would the OP code be different from this second code you posted? The OP code is saying: for operators in "*/+-" and if operators is in the string z, then..... And your code is saying for operators in string z, where operators are defined by the next "if" code of line, then...

Comment: Return breaks the for loop, so changing what you iterate over can change the returned value... if `z='/*'` in first will return `'*'...` in second will return `'/'...`

Comment: Consider `z='*/'`, then functions: `for symbol in '/*': return z.index(symbol)` and `for char in z: return z.index(char)` will return different things (1 and 0 respectively).